# Shiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*To those who like this series, sorry about the hiatus.*

*Lazy gematria for today is either awake or bad.*

Comment: Being new to this series, I'm wondering, just how far can we stretch the number? Gematria? At-Bash? Achas-Betah? English calendar years? abbreviations?

Comment: @HodofHod, people have done all sorts of things. Personally, I don't like _gimatriyaos_ unless they are sourced (by e.g. the _Baal Haturim_, i.e., don't just find some word that happens to have the right _gimatriya_), but I know others differ. I personally have answered one or two of these with Christian calendar years, but really didn't like to, and I seem to recall those answers didn't get many up-votes. But do what you want, I guess, and glean from the votes and comments how much people like them, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is tough! ummm.... Number of Synagogues in the US in 1880?
http://www.spartacus.schoolnet.co.uk/USAEjews.htm

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12130/603):

[The Chinuch calculates](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46943&pgnum=3) that there are 270 Mitzvot (48 Positive and 222 Negative) that are always applicable during exile, without needing a specific situation in order to obligate oneself (there are an additional 99 that are also applicable during exile, but only situationally). The mnemonic for this is "‫אני‬ ‫ישנה ולבי ע״ר‬" [I'm asleep but my heart is awake - in other places it explains that this refers to exile, that even while in a state of sleep (i.e. exile) we still do (at least) 270 Mitzvot]

Answer (score 1):

[The big earthquake in Turkey in August of 1912](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1912_M%C3%BCrefte_earthquake) destroyed 270 "Jewish houses" (presumably houses of Jews) in [Gallipoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelibolu), according to [*The American Jewish Year Book*](http://books.google.com/books?id=p51KAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA344&dq=houses).

Answer (score 1):

[Gabriel Wilensky reports](http://books.google.com/books?id=mJN8Bqvp30cC&pg=PA46&dq=stake) that there was [a 1421 decree against Jews issued in Vienna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Vienna#Middle_Ages) which resulted in the burning of 270 Jews, הי״ד, at the stake.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia's article on the [number 270](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/270_%28number%29) says that it is the average number of days in a human pregnancy. If "tisho yarchei leido" was good enough for echod mi yodeya ....

Comment: I haven't been able to find any other sources corroborating this number. Most either give a range or say 280 (= 40 weeks).

Answer (score -1):

במדבר: ג. מג.
ויהי כל בכור זכר במספר שמת מבן חדש ומעלה לפקדיהם שנים ועשרים אלף שלשה **ושבעים ומאתים**

Comment: So you're... taking the number modulo 1000 and rounding it to the nearest 10.

Comment: msh210 - if you have a better answer please post.

Comment: GershonGold: Touche! `:-)`