# How many of the 613 Mitzvos can we do only in Israel?

Tags: number, eretz-yisrael, mitzvah

There are many Mitzvos we can not do in today's generation. For example there are no Korbonos, no slaves, etc.

[Per the Chofetz Chaim](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=523), there are 77 positive Mitzvos and 194 negative Mitzvos which can be observed outside of Eretz Yisroel today. How many more can you keep if you live in Eretz Yisroel?

Comment: It would depend on who "we" are and what you mean by "are able to do", and, finally, your definition of Mitzvah. Certain Mitzvoth only apply if a sin was committed first. These include repaying a theft and general repentance. There are many negative Mitzvoth that only apply if one has fulfilled a positive Mitzvah that cannot be fulfilled today, but if one attempted to fulfill the positive they might be "on the hook" for the negative as well. Or not. Eg., burning leftover Korban Pesach...

Comment: The above example would be a Tikkun 'Asseh (corrective positive commandment) on the Lav (prohibition) of leaving leftovers of a Korban (sacrifice) that one may not bring today given certain restrictions, but which one could practically bring in violation of the prohibitions that are currently in place.

Comment: In other words, if someone violated current prohibitions, one could in theory set himself up for more prohibitions, which he could then violate, which could then trigger a need for a corrective positive commandment. So, he COULD observe the commandment of burning the leftovers, though it would involve multiple sins along the way. And, of course, you could count those sins as Mitzvoth that one can "keep" (by not sinning) today without the Beith HaMikdash (Holy Temple).

Comment: There are also other Mitzvoth of a nature relating to relationships, including, but not limited to, divorce and Ḥalitzah, which can only be fulfilled under circumstances that are less than desirable. Not the type of commandments one would want to fulfill. Then, of course, there is also the "theoretical" Ben Sorer UMoreh, which the Talmud tells us never happened and can't really happen.  But it's not dependent on the Temple, so much as it is on circumstances that, together, can't really happen in practical terms. So would that be counted in the "able to do" category?

Comment: Anything which is possible to do in today's generation.

Comment: Instead of saying that which is possible, I would suggest saying that which is obligatory. How many of the 613 mitzvot are obligatory today.

Comment: @avi I searched the other related questions, and I am unable to find an answer to your suggested question, "How many of the 613 mitzvot are obligatory today"? Before I ask this, I am just wondering if you can point me to where this might have been answered already.

Comment: @GershonGold Can you please put an English or German link here on the 77 positive and 194 negative Mitzvos that "Chofetz Chaim" delineated "which can be observed outside of Eretz Yisroel today"?

Comment: @ninamag: I am not aware of  a link for this in English. You can find the Sefer in English if you search on Google.

Comment: @GershonGold Yes, I will search it on Google. Apart from "Chofetz Chaim", what should I type on the search engine? What is the title of the Sefer?

Comment: @ninamag sefer hamitzvos hakatan

Comment: @GershonGold Of the 77 positive mitzvos that can be done today, have any rabbis narrowed this down? I ask this, because the mitzvah "to destroy the descendants of Amalek" is included in the "77 positive mitzvos", in fact it is listed as the 77th one, based on the list that I saw (https://rabbiyonah.files.wordpress.com/2006/02/Positive%20Commandments.pdf). I would like to kindly know why.

Comment: @ninamag I was suggesting a new question.

Comment: @avi will you post this new question? Chofetz Chaim listed 77 + and 194 - mitzvos for today; people see some problematic ones that were included, such as "to destroy the descendants of Amalek" which many think was a 1-time event; included also is the mitzvah to give a number of things to the kohen; if so, who can halachically decide who's a kohen today, etc.? If you know other problematic ones, too, let me know; I hope to read all answers when you post your question. If you're not posting a question, let me know, too.  https://rabbiyonah.files.wordpress.com/2006/02/Positive%20Commandments.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Chinuch, in his introductory letter](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46943&pgnum=3), breaks it down like this (apparently differently than the Chofetz Chaim):

- There are **613** Mizvot, **248** Positive and **365** Negative. (The Chinuch bases his sefer on the Rambam's enumeration of the Mitzvot.)
- The Total amount of Mitzvot that a person can do these days is **369**, however **99** of them (**78** Positive and **21** Negative), while still applicable, will not necessarily ever be done, since one may go through their whole life without encountering a situation where that Mitzvah applies. (e.g. paying a day laborer on that day, if someone never hires a worker, he will never have an opportunity to fulfill this Mitzvah)
- This leaves **270** Mitzvot (**48** Positive and **222** Negative) The one will always do, without having to look for situations in which a Mitzvah would apply. The mnemonic for this is **"‫אני‬
  ‫ישנה ולבי ע״ר‬"** [I'm asleep but my heart is awake - in other places it explains that this refers to exile, that even while in a state of sleep (i.e. exile) we still do (at least) 270 Mitzvot]
- However, these Mitzvot are not applicable all the time (e.g. Matzot are only a Mitvah to eat on Pesach). There are **6** Mitzvot that are applicable all the time.

Although the Chinuch does not enumerate the Mitzvot in his introduction, I think it's safe to say that the Mitzvot that can only be fulfilled in the Land of Israel are part of the 99 Mitzvot mentioned in the second bullet point. I don't know how many of those 99 are dependent on the land, though.

---

To answer your question according to the Chofetz Chaim, see [page 5 of the pdf linked to in the question](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=523). In that edition of the sefer (published in 1968), they added a list of the Mitzvot dependent on the land by Yehuda Eizenberg (I don't know who that is). His list adds an additional **37** Mitzvot that are dependent on the land (In addition to the **271** Mitzvot that are applicable outside the land).

Comment: The Shenei Luchos haBeris (hagahos on his haqdamah to Torah sheBikhsav) gives the same answer as the Chinukh.  And his use of  "‫אני‬ ‫ישנ״ה ולבי ער‬" focuses on ישנ״ה equaling 365, plus its four letters for 369. The 244 missing mitzvos equal מר״ד, rebellion, as in the cause of our exile.Might be worth insertion. (Even though I'm not a gematria fan myself. Just reporting.)

Answer (score 5):

Ben Zion Sobel, the Feldheim translator of the [Concise Book of Mitzvot](http://www.feldheim.com/concise-book-of-mitzvot-sefer-ha-mitzvot-ha-katzar.html) (from the Chafetz Haim) has added an appendix with the the commandments which are contingent on the land of Israel. He writes he did this after consulting with the [Steipler Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yisrael_Kanievsky) (R Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky) based on a 1968 list from Mosad Torah Vodaath.

He counts **26** of these mitzvot, e.g., *peah, olelot, omer ha-shikhekha, leket, truma, maaser, shmita*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In what ways does the list differ?  Also, was he including only commandments that are biblical in nature even today (e.g. without a Temple, most of Israel on their allotted share, etc.)?

Answer (score -3):

I don't know the answer but I can list what I believe/have been told are the mitzvot that one can keep living in Israel that they do not keep outside of Israel.
Wikipedia says that "The Concise book of mitzvot" writes that there are 26 mitzvot which only apply in Israel.

1. Yishuv Ha'aretz
2. Meiser
3. Trumah
4. Shmitah
5. Walking in Israel
6. Visting Yerushalaim during a chag.
7. Joining the Army
8. Davening for Rain in it's proper time. (7th of Cheshvan)
9. Peah
10. Certain berachot on the 7 species

According to one opinion (Ramban I believe?) all the mitzvot are really only required in Israel, and everything done outside of Israel is 'education'. So the answer to "how many more" might be "All of them" :)

Comment: For 2, 3 (_maaser_, _t'ruma_), you mean _hafrasha_? We do that in _chu"l_ if we buy Israeli produce. Likewise, for 4, _sh'mita_, what's the _mitzva_? If it's not working the land, then I guess I do that, living in _chu"l_; if it's treating produce right, then we can do that with Israeli produce in _chu"l_; or what? 5, walking in Israel, 6, visiting J-m, and 7, enlisting: are those _mitzvos_?? For 8, praying at the "proper time" for rain, I do pray at the proper time, Dec. 5. And what's 10, "certain" _b'rachos_? Never heard of that one.

Comment: I'm not sure you are fulfilling those mitzvot when you do them in *Chu"l*.  According to the Rambam and Ramban and later Rav Kook,  5,6 and 7 are 100% miztvot. As for 8, that is not the "proper time" for Israel. (it's also not the proper time in Chu'l but that's a different topic about how calendars work.) There are special brachot you say when planting those species.

Comment: @avi Can you provide the text of a blessing recited when planting the seven species in Israel? Or a link to discussion thereof?