# Mitzvot of the Land of Israel

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, mitzvah

Can someone post a concise list of the mitzvot that are applicable on in or to eretz yisrael today?  Or a link to such a list?  Wikipedia and others discuss all the ones that have ever existed, then half-heartedly mention that many don't apply now, but I can't find a clear list of currently applicable ones.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/how-many-of-the-613-mitzvos-are-we-able-to-do-currently

Comment: Oh, hm. Thanks @sam; this appears to be a duplicate of that question. Closing....