# Source for 37 Israeli Mitzvot Today

Tags: mitzvah, eretz-yisrael, contemporary-halacha

According to the accepted answer of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/how-many-of-the-613-mitzvos-can-we-do-only-in-israel), there are 37 *mitzvot* unique to the land of Israel that one can fulfill nowadays. Notably, however, he includes in that count *mitzvot* such as those related to *issur chodosh*, that according to the overwhelming majority of authorities, are also biblically mandated outside Israel.  He also includes *mitzvot* related to, e.g. *teruma*, *maaser*, and *shemita*, which, at least according to many authorities, are only *drabanan* (rabbinic) nowadays.  Is there *any* (other) authority, e.g., amongst the *rishonim*, that would agree with this list?

Comment: There's no reason to expect that the way any posek nowadays ends up deciding what is Deorayta and what is Derabanan should align perfectly with any particular Rishon, since there are so many machlokot and hence permutations

Comment: @DoubleAA "e.g." (I asked for *any* authority.)

Comment: Well then the answer is trivially yes, since the list in that answer was published by an authority...

Comment: @DoubleAA Assuming Rav Eisenberg actually paskens according to that list and did not mean it as a theoretical, largest number possible.  I've edited accordingly just in case. (Also, if he meant as you said, there should hae been explicit acknowledgment as such rather than a shaar daf that still implies the list is according to the rambam/rishonim.)

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92787/11501